# Every locally compact, Hausdorff, second-countable space has a countable basis consisting of open sets with compact closure

Tags: general-topology

[image]

I'm trying to understand the proof of this lemma. My problem lies in the existence of $V_{n(x)}$. As far as I know (from Munkres' topology), there should be a neighborhood $U_x$ of $x$ such that $\overline{U_x}$ is compact and $\overline{U_p}\subseteq V_{n(x)}$. Can anyone show me how? Thanks.

Comment: The weight $w(X)$ of a space $X$ is the least infinite cardinal $k$ such that $X$ has a base $B$ with cardinal $|B|\le k.$ (We can say " with $|B|=k$" if $X$ does not have a finite base). Theorem: If $C$ is a base for a space $X$ then $X$ has a base $B\subset C$ with $|B|\le w(X)$.... So for your Q it suffices  that the family $C$ of all open subsets with compact closures is a base for $X.$

Comment: related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4030200/does-a-second-countable-locally-compact-hausdorff-space-admit-a-countable-basi?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That there is an open set $U_x$ containing $x$ with $\overline {U_x}$ compact is a theorem on locally compact Hausdorff spaces. There there exists some $V_n=V_{n(x)}$ contained in $U_x$ and containing $x$ because $(V_n)$ is a base. Since $V_{n(x)} \subset U_x$ it follows that the closure of $V_{n(x)} $ is compact. Since $(V_{n(x)})$ is a sub-collection of $(V_n)$ is is countable. That finishes the proof.

Edit: as pointed out by Steve it is not clear that $(V_{n(x)})$ is a base. So the proof has to me modified as follows: let $U$ be any open set and $x \in U$. Pick $U_x$ as above. Then there exists $V_{n(x)}$ such that $x \in V_{n(x)} \subset U \cap U_x$. Rest is now clear.

Comment: Sir, how come does $V_{n(x)}$ become a basis? Thank you.

Comment: Let $U$ be an open set and let $q\in U$. If $\exists V\in\{V_{n(x)}\}$ s.t. $q\in V\subseteq U$, then $\{V_{n(x)}\}$ will be a basis. To find $V$, we may well consider $V_{n(q)}$ since $q$ is already in $V_{n(q)}$. But how about $V_{n(q)}\subseteq U$? I don't how to fix it.

Comment: correction: How could $\{V_{n(x)}\}$ be a basis?

Comment: @Steve I have edited the proof.

Answer (score 1):

$\{V_n\}$ is a basis for the topology. Then by definition, given any open set $U$ and a point $x\in U$, we can find a basis element $V_{n(x)}$ such that $x\in V_{n(x)}\subset U$.

Answer (score 1):

> My problem lies in the existence of $V_{n(x)}$.

Given any open set $U$ at all around $x$, the phrase "$\{V_n\}$ is a basis of the topology" means that one of the $V_n$'s can get inside of $U$ and around $x$ too. This explains the existence of $V_{n(x)}$.